# Is it possible in MongoDB to match exact field value from unpredicted text?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My Idea is to match the pattern i.e='8021370000' from both the collection field and text.

Example text:

```
const text = "ATM #TRFLA TRF MYVA80213700000102SMS 0099890#VALLEN"
```

Example record:

```
{
  _id: 5f3a5d00cc16d45d973ecbc1,
  pattern: '8021370000'
}
```

I do regex, but it doesn't work

```
db.collection.find( { pattern: { $regex: text } } )
```

Is it possible to match the pattern from the full text to the pattern of the record?

Comment: The `$regex` search in MongoDB works the other way around: Find a pattern (substring) in the field values (big string) of docs

Comment: I do fetch all docs of collection. Then I loop for each doc and use regex to match with the text. But is it possible to perform matching like that from MongoDB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$regex` search in MongoDB works the other way around: Find docs in a collection, where a field value (longer string) matches a search string (short text).

To find docs, where the field value can be found in a bigger search string you need to iterate over the docs. Here is an example using `.indexOf()` for a literal sub-string match (you can changed that to a regex match if needed) :

```
const text = "ATM #TRFLA TRF MYVA80213700000102SMS 0099890#VALLEN"
let docs = [];
db.example.find(
  {}
).forEach(function (doc) {
  if(text.indexOf(doc.pattern) >= 0) {
    docs.push(doc);
  }
});
```

The resulting `docs` array has all docs where `docs.pattern` can be found in `text`